# Install windows in External SSD using Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows, ssd

currently I am using Ubuntu 20.04 os in my Laptop. I have bought an 256gb external SSD recently.

I want to install windows 10/11 in my external SSD. But I don't know if I can use Rufus software in ubuntu or I need to use different steps for that or If you can share any youtube video link which will solve my problem. Please let me know if anyone can help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Microsoft does not allow installs to external drives. It is licensed to one system only, so cannot be booted on other systems.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to AskUbuntu. 
What to use to make/how to make a Windows stick:
You can use 'Ventoy'. Advantage: you can put multiple `iso's` on 1 stick. 
Or you can do it as explained on It'sFoss. See https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/. 
Or check out omg!ubuntu at https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/create-bootable-windows-10-usb-ubuntu. 
Personally I love Ventoy for the reason mentioned.
How to install Windows on external drive:
On `Youtube` see for instance:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwKp8E2xIAc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jihiqau8O3k
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-R7BUTYCfU
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68rkbLuxOSE

  There are plenty more. Just search for `install windows 10 on external drive` or `install windows 11 on external drive`.

Comment: Wow Thank you so much for making it easier for me. One more question, The steps shows that I need 1 usb pen drive which I will make bootable + External ssd/hdd where i want to install the os....... But Can I make ssd bootable and install os in the same ssd?

Comment: If you devide it in partitions maybe, but I think you complicate things by doing that.

Comment: Later when all the links no longer work this will not make much of an answer.

Comment: @David Yes I know, but for now it helped Nayem.He asked for links, I provided them. I can edit my answer later.